# Range bit inversions and range set bit queries with a binary indexed tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees, intervals

I am trying to solve [this](http://www.codechef.com/problems/FLIPCOIN) problem using a binary indexed tree. The problem can be summarized as follows:

> You are given a series of commands that operate on an array initially
>   all zeroes.
>
> 1) Invert all bits from [a, b] (1 becomes a 0 and vice-versa)
>
> 2) Find the number of set
>   bits from [a, b] (bits that have value 1).

I know that one way to solve this is using a segment tree with lazy propagation, but I want to see whether it can be solved using a binary indexed tree.

---

To start, I know that binary indexed trees can be used to do range increments and range sums as per my [previous](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33014/range-update-range-query-with-binary-indexed-trees) question.

Further, I know that the structure of a binary indexed tree is that the node $i$ stores a function of values form $i - 2^h + 1$ to $i$ where $h$ is $i \text{ and}-i$ which is sort of similar to a segment tree in which each node stores the merged value of its left and right children (2i and 2i + 1 in the array representation).

Binary indexed trees only operate on functions that are associative and have an inverse, (that is, function[a..b] = function[0..b] - function[0..a-1]). On the other hand, segment trees only need a function that is associative, as the range is built directly from smaller segments rather than being a difference of two other ranges.

Finding the number of set bits does seem to be a function where numSetBits[a...b] = numSetBits[0...b] - numSetBits[0...a-1]

except that inversion is not such a function. Could binary indexed trees somehow be cleverly modified (like was done to support range queries and updates) in order to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you explain what is an associative function? I know the concept of associative operators, but not certain on associative function.

Comment: I don't think associative function is a formal term. Just one I made up. It is essentially a function that can operate across a range of values (like addition where you add each element in the list) and the following is true: f[a..b] + f[b..c] = f[a..c].

Comment: In that case, you need to have a kind of ordering on the function's domain which is also not a thing I know of when defining a function.